# How we can upgrade the python version to the latest one on ubuntu mate using banana pi

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, banana-pi

I am stuck in the terminal with an old version so I want to upgrade it and I want the best way to code using Python on the Banana Pi chip other than using the terminal

Downloading from google the latest version of Python did not work and also the sedo commands have been difficult to deal with

Comment: Are you updating Bookworm?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.